# Why does \clearpage messes up two-column references?

Tags: floats, bibliographies, clearpage

I have a `LaTeX` file containing several images and one table to be printed before the "References" Section. I managed to get all figures printed in an appropriate position using the `\clearpage` command right before the references. However, somehow the command messes up my references and the result is the following references page:
[image]

Without `\clearpage` my references are OK, but the images are printed in an incorrect position. With the `\clearpage` the abovecited problem happens... any idea of how I can solve this?

This is my reference style:

```
\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
```

Comment: What did you do before ` \clearpage
\bibliographystyle{abbrv} `

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use. Please also tell us how and where the `\bibliography` instruction is placed. Or do you build the contents of the `thebibliography` environment by hand? Please advise.

Comment: I'm using a conference class that is mostly copied from sig-alternate.cls [link] (http://ipsn.acm.org/2011/cameraready_files/sig-alternate.cls). The \bibliography command is using a .bib file, and before the \clearpage I have a normal text concluding the paper. @bttX

Comment: Does new paragraph (free line) between `\clearpage` and `\bibliographystyle` help?

Comment: @KolaB. Nothing changes :(

Comment: You might try forcing the last float before the references to be full-page only.  This would probably work only if that page is the last page before the references.  If there is text that doesn't fill the entire last column, then try putting `\vspace{fill}` before the `\clearpage`.  (These are just guesses.  There's not enough information here to experiment without guessing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some days struggling with `LaTeX`, I finally managed to get a good-looking solution.

I had to add `\usepackage{dblfloatfix}` in my preamble

Comment: This did unfortunately not help me. Does anyone have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead of `\clearpage`:

```
\newpage
\twocolumn[
\begin{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\end{center}
]
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{egbib}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/247638)